# What's the correct way to load keras_model.h5 and labels.txt in Google Apps Script?

Tags: tensorflow, google-apps-script, keras, tf.keras, image-classification

I'm trying to load a trained (using Teachable machine) Keras model and labels file into a Google Apps Script to classify images on Google Drive.

The model and labels files are also on Google Drive.

Below is the code I'm trying and getting the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isTypedArray')
V4
F5
Dte
classifyImages  @ Code.gs:50

Seems like an issue with loading the keras_model.h5 file.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

This is my current code.

```
function classifyImages() {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs').getContentText());

  // Get the folder that contains the images
  var imagesFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('IMAGE_FOLDER_ID');

  // Get the TensorFlow Keras model file
  var modelFile = DriveApp.getFileById('KERAS_MODEL_H5_FILE_ID');

  // Get the labels file
  var labelsFile = DriveApp.getFileById('LABELS_TXT_FILE_ID');

  // Load the TensorFlow Keras model
  const modelContent = modelFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const byteArray = [...modelContent].map((char) => char.charCodeAt(0));
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(byteArray);

  var loadModelPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.fromMemory(uint8Array))
      .then(function (model) {
        resolve(model);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        reject(error);
      });
  });

  // Read the labels file
  const labelsContent = labelsFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const lines = labelsContent.split('\n');
  var labels = lines.map(function (line) {
    var parts = line.split(' ');
    return parts[1];
  });

  // Loop through the images in the images folder
  var files = imagesFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    // If the file is an image
    if (file.getMimeType().startsWith('image/')) {
      // Print the file name
      Logger.log('Processing image: ' + file.getName());

      // Convert the image to a TensorFlow tensor
      var imageBlob = file.getBlob();
      var imageBytes = imageBlob.getBytes();
      var imageArray = Array.from(imageBytes);
      var imageTensor = tf.tensor1d(imageArray);

      // Classify the image
      var prediction;

      loadModelPromise
        .then(function (model) {
          prediction = model.predict(imageTensor.reshape([1, imageTensor.size]));

          // Get the top prediction
          var topPrediction = prediction.argMax();

          // Get the label for the top prediction
          var label = labels[topPrediction.dataSync()[0]];

          // Display the classification result
          Logger.log('The image ' + file.getName() + ' is classified as ' + label);

          // Create a new folder for the classified image
          var subfolder = imagesFolder.createFolder(label);

          // Move the image to the new folder
          file.moveTo(subfolder);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          Logger.log('Error processing image: ' + file.getName() + '. Error message: ' + error);
        });
    }
  }

  // Log completion message
  Logger.log('Image classification and movement completed.');
}
```